# React MUI Animation Slide not working with SVG Icon

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slide

My Slide component with svg picture is not working. It's just showing a white box moving from left to right, (with no actual picture). How can I get this to work?

Following the documentation here: https://mui.com/material-ui/transitions/

```
import { Paper, Slide } from '@material-ui/core';
import OfficeWorker from './OfficeWorker.svg';

const TestButtons = () => {
  const [buyButtonClicked, setBuyButtonClicked] = useState(false);

  const onBuyNow = () => {
    setBuyButtonClicked(true);
  };

  const OfficeWorkerIcon = (
    <Paper elevation={4}>
      <Box component="svg">
        <img src={OfficeWorker} />
      </Box>
    </Paper>
  );

  return (
    <Box>
      <Box marginRight={3}>
        <Button onClick={onBuyNow}>
          Buy it now
        </Button>
        <Button display="flex">Questions? Give us a call!</Button>
      </Box>

      <Slide direction="right" in={buyButtonClicked} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
        {OfficeWorkerIcon}
      </Slide>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default TestButtons;
```

Only a WhiteBox shows from Left to Right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use svg files out of the box in React like you are. What I recommend you do is go to https://react-svgr.com/playground/. This is a nice tool that converts an SVG into a react friendly component.

You can take the contents of svg file and paste it into that site like so:

[image]

Then copy the JSX Output. Use it to create a component in your application. Import and use that component in your Slide animation. NOTE: I couldn't get it work placing the svg component directly inside of the Slide component. I had to use a Box.

```
<Slide direction="right" in={buyButtonClicked} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
  <Box>
    <SvgComponent />
  </Box>
</Slide>;
```

That's the easiest way. If you want to do a deeper dive, check out this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-react/) which goes over how to change webpack configuration file to allow using svg files in React.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MUI's SvgIcon component, available at: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/svg-icon/

Just place your SVG icon inside the tag and the slider will work as expected.

```html
import { SvgIcon, Slide, Box } from '@mui/material';
import { TbSquareRoundedNumber1Filled } from 'react-icons/tb'

<Slide direction="right" in={buyButtonClicked} mountOnEnter unmountOnExit>
  <Box>
    <SvgIcon style={{ fontSize: "80px" }} inheritViewBox >
      // your icon tag or path...
      // example: <TbSquareRoundedNumber1Filled color='#77b142' />
    </SvgIcon>
  </Box>
</Slide>
```